# update table data after inserting from a modal in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am starting with angular and I want my table to update with the new data after inserting from a modal, do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

this is my depotComponent.ts from where I call the modal

```
export class DeptoComponent implements OnInit{

displayedColumns: string[] = ['Id', 'Nombre', 'Descripcion', 'Acciones'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

  constructor(
    private deptoSvc: DeptoService, 
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

this.deptoSvc.getAll().subscribe((depto) => {

  this.dataSource.data = depto;

})


}

onOpenModal(depto={}): void{
    this.dialog.open(DeptoModalComponent, {
      height:'300px',
      width: '600px',
      hasBackdrop: false,
      data: { title: 'Nueva Departamento', depto},
    });
  }
}
```

this is the onSave method of the modal-component.ts

```
onSave(): void{

    const formValue = this.deptoForm.baseForm.value;

    if(this.actionTODO == Action.NEW){
      this.deptoSvc.new(formValue, this.file).subscribe( (res) => {

        location.reload()
        this._snackBar.open('Departamento agregado correctamente', 'Aceptar', { duration: 2000});
        
      });

    }else{

      const deptoId = this.data?.depto?.id;
      this.deptoSvc.update(deptoId, formValue, this.file).subscribe( (res) => {
        this._snackBar.open('Departamento actualizado correctamente', 'Aceptar', { duration: 2000});
      })

    }
  }
```

thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Reload the table data on afterClose() callback of dialogRef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to call the service in the parent component than in modal.

Get DialogRef in modal component, and if you save you can also close the dialog.

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeptoModalComponent>)
{...}

OnSave(): void {
 .....
 this.dialogRef.close(value); //value is data for service
}
```

Parent Component after dialog open

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeptoModalComponent, {
          height:'300px',
          width: '600px',
          hasBackdrop: false,
          data: { title: 'Nueva Departamento', depto},
        });
    
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
     /* result is came from dialogRef.close(), feel free to use.
       You can add manually new element into datasource to avoid unnecessary service call. */
});
```

For details, check [Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)